# Tracking andorid API's used by other application installed on phone

Tags: java, android

I am building an android application, but i am very beginner to this.
I want to track the API's used by other applications installed in phone, for example i want to know which applications are used or using camera. like this i want to know what other applications are doing?...so please help me to achieve this

Answer (score -1):

Here are two open-source projects that might provide what you are looking for:
[OSMonitor](https://github.com/eolwral/OSMonitor), and 
[Android Device Info](https://github.com/menny/android-device-info)

Comment: i am getting an error while configuring the application in Android studio.       Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.